# How to enable syscall auditing in CoreOs?

Tags: linux, audit, coreos, auditd, journald

Since CoreOs 766, the [auditing subsystem](https://coreos.com/releases/) is partially integrated:

> The audit subsystem has been enabled in the kernel and auditctl added
>   to the image. Most audit events are ignored by default. The audit
>   rules may be modified in /etc/audit/rules.d. Note that auditd is not
>   included, journald is responsible for logging events instead although
>   it is a best effort mechanism. Unlike with auditd based systems the
>   kernel will not panic if journald fails to record an event for some
>   reason.

I have tried the following in order to audit syscalls on both 899 and alpha 1000 CoreOs releases.

```
# starting a new periodic process:
$ while true; do echo "coreos ..." > /tmp/a.txt && sleep 5s; done &
[1] 4509

# get its pid and add a new audit rule:
$ sudo auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S read,write,close,dup2,wait4 -F pid=4509

# wait 5 minutes and check if any audit related event was logged into by the journald:
$ journalctl | grep audit | wc
      0       0       0
```

Why can't I see any event that's logged by the journald?

The `cn.ko` is loaded properly and according the `auditctl -l` output the rule is set successfully. Though it looks like `journald` doesn't receive messages from the netlink interface.

I followed the following steps in order to enable debugging but it didn't give any hints either:

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service.d/
```

`vim /etc/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service.d/10-debug.conf` and filled it with following content:

```
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

And restart systemd-journald service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart systemd-journald
dmesg | grep systemd-journald
```

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't ask this question of the CoreOS project directly https://coreos.com/community/. Especially as this is a new feature and people in business environments (our target audience) don't usually use bleeding edge releases.

Comment: @Iain I _still_ don't know how or when CoreOS would make sense to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CoreOS ships with a set of default rules and is designed to be configured via the filesystem in `/etc/audit/rules.d/`. As you are trying to play with it interactively what you will want to do is clear the audit rules first as there is a rule at `/etc/audit/rules.d/99-default.rules` that silences all remaining rules.

Simply run `audit -D` to clear the rules and then your interactively added rules should start working.

FWIW, the rule from `99-default.rules` that is causing trouble is `-a exclude,always -F msgtype>0`.

Comment: As with many of the `*.d` directories, the contents are loaded in lexical order.  Using `99-` as the prefix ensures that rules can be easily added before (e.g. `00` through `98`) as well as be added afterwards (e.g. beginning with alphabetic characters).  For more information as to *why* that rule has specific mechanics read the man pages for `audit.rules` and `auditctl`.